# Diferença entre null, empty, 0 e false

Tags: php, tipagem

### O objetivo

Diferenciar o uso no dia-a-dia de `null`, `empty`, `0` e `false`.

### O problema

Lidar todos os dias com essas 4 representações de variáveis é complicado e eu não sei diferenciá-las, ainda mais com o PHP que parece tratar elas todas iguais.

Comment: Guilherme, você poderia editar a pergunta para que ela soe como uma pergunta, e não como uma introdução à resposta? Acredito que assim ela funcione melhor na nossa plataforma. Ah, e é totalmente válido perguntar e responder sua própria pergunta; não precisa marcar a resposta como wiki, é justo ganhar pontos por ela.

Comment: @bfavaretto Pronto, meu caro. Obrigado pelas dicas!

Comment: Poderíamos considerar o empty como sendo um espaço?

Comment: Uma boa dica (como sempre) é a documentação oficial. Esse Apêndice da documentação mostra como as diferentes funções de teste de variáveis funcionam em cima de valores diferentes com tipos diferentes. http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Cenário

Eu saí do PHP para me aventurar no mundo do C# e senti uma dificuldade imensa para entender um pouco sobre tipagens. Aliás, demorei pra entender porque eu não conseguia comparar uma **string** com **null** para fazer algo caso a string estivesse **vazia**.

Depois de um tempo matutando o problema na cabeça, caí à fundo na internet e corri atrás. Eis que a solução vem a seguir.

---

### O que é "0"?

Zero é zero e ponto. Quem pode ser zero é um número, não uma letra ou um espaço vazio. Zero é zero e fim de papo.

Em PHP:

```php
$n = 0;

if ($n === 0)
    // true

if ($n === '0')
    // false
```

Para explicar: as três igualdades adjacentes significam **exatamente igual**. Que, por sua vez, significa **conteúdo/valor** e **tipo** igual.

Na primeira condicional, temos `true` como comentário porque `$n` é um inteiro/número, e seu valor é `0`. Ou seja, o conteúdo **E** a tipagem são iguais.

Na segunda condicional, o comentário é `false` porque ele compara `$n` com `'0'`, sendo o zero, neste caso, uma string.

Resumidamente, **número** é uma ciosa e **string** é outra. Embora sejam dois zeros, são de **tipos distintos**.

### O que é o "empty"?

Quando você tem uma variável do tipo **string** e deseja verificar se ela têm algum preenchimento, você utiliza o **empty** para fazer a comparação.

Em suma, ele verifica se uma string possui ou não conteúdo; se está ou não vazia.

### O que é o "null"?

**null** significa **nulo**. Você compara **nulo** quando você sabe que uma variável tem a chance de possivelmente não trazer nada.

Querem um exemplo prático?

```php
<?php

class Cachorro
{
    public $estado;

    public function sentar()
    {
        if ($this->estado != 'sentado')
            $this->estado = 'sentado';
    }
}
```

Como podemos ver, criei uma classe `Cachorro` e um método `sentar`. Antes de o cachorro sentar, nós verificamos o estado dele. Se já estiver sentado, **ele não fará nada**, ou seja, **a função *não* vai retornar nada (`null`)**; do contrário, ele alterará o seu `estado` para `sentado`.

Para facilitar, se um cachorro treinado ganhar a ordem de sentar quando ele já estiver sentado, ele provavelmente vai continuar daquele jeito e não vai te retornar nada além do aguardo de um próximo comando (*null*) ou talvez de um biscoito por ter executado uma tarefa com tanta maestria.

**Atenção:** o termo `null` não tem apenas fins conceituais ou didáticos. `null` também especifica que uma variável não está alocada na memória. Por exemplo, se temos uma variável `$x = 0` e depois mudamos para `$x = null`, então nós fizemos uma desalocação de dado. Em outras palavras, removemos uma informação da memória.

### E por fim, o que é "false"?

Se alguém perguntar se você está com calor, na maioria das vezes, há duas opções de resposta: `true` ou `false`. Você provavelmente não vai falar `0` ou vai deixar de responder (`empty`). Você vai dizer *sim* ou *não*. E é exatamente isso que o `true` e `false` são.

```php
<?php

class Cachorro
{
    // ...

    public function latir()
    {
        echo 'Woof!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, o método `latir()` vai retornar `true`.

```php
<?php

if ($cachorro->latir())
    echo 'O cachorro latiu!';
else
    echo 'O cachorro não latiu. :(';
```

E de acordo com a condicional acima, duas coisas vão ser exibidas:

> 1. 'Woof!'
> 2. 'O cachorro latiu!';

Juntando:

> 1. 'Woof!O cachorro latiu!';

Por que isso acontece?

Ora, no `if` você está executando uma função e verificando ***se* o retorno dela é *verdadeiro***. Se for, exiba `O cachorro latiu!`. E é verdadeiro?... Claro que sim! Isso está explícito no `return` do método `latir()` da classe `Cachorro`.

### `null` vs. `false`, `empty` e `0`

Pegando o exemplo anterior, mas removendo o `return`:

```php
<?php

class Cachorro
{
    // ...

    public function latir()
    {
        echo 'Woof!';
    }
}
```

Qual será o tipo que `latir()` vai retornar? *Tchã tchã tchã tchã*

E o tipo será.............. *null*!

Para fazer uma comparação de nulos na prática, siga o modelo:

```php
if ($cachorro->latir() == null)
    // faça algo
```

Answer (score 3):

**NULL**
Indica que uma variável não tem valor. Uma variável é considerada NULL se tiver sido atribuído como NULL (valor especial), ou se ainda não tiver sido atribuído um valor à variável.

**empty**
É um construtor de linguagem e não uma função e é usada para determinar se a variável é considerada vazia.
É avaliado como empty (vazio) os seguintes valores:

- "" (string vazia)
- 0 (0 como inteiro)
- "0" (0 como string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (array vazio)
- var $var; (variável declarada, mas sem valor)

**Sobre True, False ou 0:**

Um dado booleano só pode conter dois valores: verdadeiro (**true**) ou falso (**false**).

Mas a grande dúvida surge quando se vai comparar valores no PHP que por não ser uma linguagem fortemente tipada, **faz conversões automáticas dependendo do tipo de comparação**:

Quando a conversão de dados de e para o tipo booleano, várias regras especiais se aplicam:

Um número (inteiro ou ponto flutuante) convertido em um valor booleano torna-se false se o valor original é zero, e true o contrário.

A string é convertida para false apenas se estiver vazia ou se ele contém o caráter único '0'. Se ela contém qualquer outra coisa, até mesmo dados vários zeros, ele é convertido para true.

Quando convertida para um número ou uma string, um valor booleano torna-se 1, quando true, e 0 caso false.

*É importante entender que todos os operadores lógicos somente trabalha com valores booleanos;  portanto, o PHP irá converter qualquer outro valor para um valor booleano e, em seguida, realizar a operação.*

O PHP usa os seguintes operadores da seguinte forma:

**==** Equivalência.
Avalia como true se os dois operandos são equivalentes, o que significa que eles podem ser convertidos para um tipo de dados em comum que eles têm o mesmo valor, mas não são necessariamente o mesmo tipo de dado (aplica-se a regra acima).

**===** Identidade. 
Avalia como true somente se os operandos são do mesmo tipo de dados e têm o mesmo valor (não se aplica a regra de conversão neste caso).

**!=** Não Equivalente
Avalia como true se os dois operandos são não equivalentes, sem relação ao seu tipo de dados.

**!==** Não identicos
Operador não-idênticos. Avalia como true se os dois operandos não são do mesmo tipo de dados ou não tem o mesmo valor.

Espero ter ajudado, as informações foram adaptadas por mim do livro Zend PHP 5 Certification Study Guide e da documentação oficial.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que o problema aqui seria a diferenciação de tipos e não 'apenas' de valores. Todos os valores perguntados (`null`, `0`, `empty` e `false`) são de diferentes tipos. E o PHP, talvez por convenção ou talvez por simplificação (ou por um erro crasso mesmo,) resolveu utilizar como utiliza, mas o porquê não vem ao caso. Vamos aos tipos:

## null

Ou nulo em português, é simplesmente a ausência de valor, `null` é do tipo `null` e ponto. Este tipo está extremamente ligado a função `isset`. Esta função verifica se o valor realmente existe, como por exemplo:

```
<?php

class Pessoa
{
    public $nome = 'Fulaninho';

    public function __construct($nome = null)
    {
        if (isset($nome)) {
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }
    }
}
```

## 0 (zero)

Como já respondido, zero é zero e ponto. Mas zero é um inteiro (um número) diferente de `'0'` (uma string). Se voce tiver que usar uma função que retorne um valor numérico, force o PHP a dizer que aquele zero é um número e não uma string usando 'intval' ou "type casting" para `(int)`. Algo como:

```
<?php

$zero   = '0'; 
$numero = intval($zero); // ou $numero = (int) $zero;
```

## empty (ou string vazia)

Muito confundido com `null`, `empty` é apenas uma string vazia, algo como:

```
<?php

$vazio = '';

if ('' === $vazio) #=> true
if (null === $vazio) #=> false
```

## false

`false` é um booleano (o contrário de `true`.)

Se voce faz uma pergunta ao computador: 
 - `true` seria a resposta `sim` e 
 - `false` seria `não`.

Simples assim.

## O grande problema é que...

O PHP faz uma grande bagunça com os tipos, olha só:

```
<?php

if (0 == false) // true
if (null == false) // true
if ('' == false) // true
```

## Meus conselhos

*Aqui é uma preferencia minha, eu tenho certeza que outros programadores discordem de mim. Acho que não existe certo ou errado, apenas estilos diferentes de programar.*

#### Evite retornar diferentes tipos

Se a tua função/método retornar um `array` de clientes e, por algum acaso, não tiver nenhum, retorne um `array` vazio. Se retornar uma string e por algum acaso esteja vazia, retorne `empty`. E assim por diante. Evite `null`ar tudo. Evitando coisas do tipo: essa função retorna uma `string` ou `null`.

#### O triplo igual `===` é teu melhor amigo

Por favor, use sem moderação.

```
<?php

if (0 === false) // false
if (null === false) // false
if ('' === false) // false

// como deve ser
```

#### Siga alguns padrões

A comunidade PHP em conjunto criou alguns padrões para uso e criou o site [PHP the right way](http://br.phptherightway.com/) (link em português!) para apresentar o que foi criado.

Answer (score 0):

O **empty** não seria como um "espaço", pois sendo assim ele seria uma string vazia.
O **empty** é quando uma variável existe, mas sem nenhum valor definido para ela.

Exemplo:

```
$variavel = ""; // Ela existe, porém é vazia. Neste caso, é uma variável empty.
$variavel = " "; // Desta forma a variável não é empty, tendo um valor definido(espaço)
$variavel = null; // Neste caso, a variável deixa de existir.
```