# Porque o isset não funciona bem com $_POST?

Tags: php

Preciso que o título da página varie de acordo com o form, para isso eu usei o código dentro do `<head>`:

```
<?php
    $titulo = isset($_POST['titulo']) ? $_POST['titulo'] : 'Sem titulo';
?>
<title><?php echo $titulo." - Minimalist";?></title>
```

Ele funciona bem caso eu adicione o título no form, mas não retorna o 'Sem título', quando o mesmo for vazio. Isso funcionava perfeitamente com o `$_GET`. Por acaso, ao usar o `$_POST`, ele retorna uma *string* vazia?

Comment: exato..   para tirar a prova faça `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90026/4793

Comment: Você diz que em `$_GET` funcionava, mas depende de como você estava alimentando o `$_GET`, se simplemente remover/omitir a variável do link href, esta certo, o `isset` vai retornar `false`, mas se for por envio de um formulário, tanto em get como post, mesmo que deixe o campo em branco, eles terão as variáveis definidas como `NULL`, neste caso o `isset` vai retornar `true`...

Comment: @DanielOmine Acho que não é uma duplicada, aquela é sobre como validar os dados recebidos do formulário, essa no entanto, foca no `isset` e `$_POST` especificamente.

Comment: @JaderA.Wagner sim, amigo, funcionava omitindo da URL.

Comment: Nessa outra que marquei como duplicada mostra isso que pede aqui e mais detalhes essenciais, inclusive, ao ler pode entender o motivo do negativo na resposta.

Comment: ahh.. para não ficar muito vago, em partes é certo o que respondeu, mas nem sempre o post trará o index especificado. No caso do índice não existir, ao entrar no `empty()`, emitirá o erro de index undefined pois o `empty()` não faz a função do `isset()`. E é esse o problema aqui. Pode até funcionar mas é uma má prática.

Comment: @DanielOmine Na verdade faz sim, porém não emite o erro caso a variável não esteja definida, apenas retorna **falso**. O `empty` internamente faz isso: `!isset($foo) || !$foo`. Veja [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/1608936) e [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7191642/1608936) para detalhes. O `empty` neste caso é válido, pois o AP quer verificar se a variável está vazia.

Comment: Se você quiser se sentir mais seguro pode fazer algo assim: `isset($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['titulo'])` mas é meio redundante. ;-)

Comment: O problema mesmo não é a redundância. É a consistência. Pois como o `empty()` retorna o mesmo valor para ambos os casos (nulo, vazio ou undefined retorna true), torna o resultado passível a ambiguidade. Suponha que você quer receber uma variável. Ela é obrigatória mas pode ser vazia. E aí? rsrsr Parece estranho mas existem situações assim e são comuns. Daí vem a concepção de que o uso dessa forma é uma má prática. Na verdade uma má prática "porcamente" permitida pelo PHP.

Comment: @DanielOmine Ai é um caso para usar o `isset`. =) Atualizei a resposta e coloquei outra alternativa também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) verifica se uma variável foi definida/inicializada, não é verificado se possuí um valor.

O `isset` sempre vai retornar `true` para [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) porque ele vai estar sempre definido, porém pode estar vazio, que é provavelmente a origem do teu problema.

Veja a documentação do `$_POST`:

> Esta é uma [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php), ou global automática, variável. Isto
>   simplesmente significa que ela está disponível em todos escopos pelo
>   *script*.

Para verificar se a variável está vazia, use o [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php):

```
$titulo = empty($_POST['titulo']) ? 'Sem titulo' : $_POST['titulo'];
```

Semelhante ao `isset`, o `empty` também verifica se a variável foi inicializada, porém **não emite um aviso**. O que é considerado vazio pelo `empty`:

- `""`  (uma *string* vazia)
- `0`   (*0* como um inteiro)
- `0.0` (*0* como um ponto flutuante)
- `"0"` (*0* como uma *string*)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (um `array` vazio)
- `$var;`   (uma variável declarada, mas sem valor)

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-parameters), o `empty` é essencialmente equivalente a `!isset($var) || $var == false`.

---

Uma outra alternativa é usar o `isset` e uma condição para verificar se variável não está vazia:

```
$titulo = isset($_POST['titulo']) && $_POST['titulo'] !== '' ? 
                                     $_POST['titulo'] : 'Sem titulo';
```

Veja também:

- [Tabela de comparações de tipos do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php)
- [Diferença entre `null`, `empty`, 0 e `false`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2639/6454)

Comment: Funcionou, mas corrija a ordem do empty, está trocada.

Comment: @DanielBonifácio Corrigido!