# Como Preencher zero em campo quando o campo está vazio em PHP?

Tags: php, php-7

O campo LIMITE_SUPERIOR é de tipo real. Gostaria de saber como faço para lhe dizer que se está vazio preenche número 0 no campo e quando não está vazio pode preencher o numéro que ele achou dentro do banco de dados.

```
$examesEquipamentos = [];
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
    $examesEquipamentosId = trim($linha['ID']) . '-' . trim($linha['ID_TR']);
    if (!array_key_exists($examesEquipamentosId, $examesEquipamentos)) {
        $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = [
            'ID' => trim($linha['ID']),
            'NOME_PARAMETRO' => trim($linha['NOME_PARAMETRO']),
            'ID_TR' => trim($linha['ID_TR']),
            'TR_NOME' => trim(mb_strtoupper($linha['TR_NOME'])),
            'UNIDADE_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']),
            'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']),
            'LIMITE_INFERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_INFERIOR']),
            'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']),
        ];

    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem, no caso caso ele retorne nulo ou vazio quer que seja retornado 0 ?

Comment: @Gladiador Se ele é um `float` porque está dando `trim()` nele? É uma string, não?

Comment: ele pegar o valor pelo arquivo csv. e esse csv tem campo com preenchidos e campos vazios. então em vezes de retornar os campos vazios queria colocar zero no lugar  em vez de me retornar um campo vazio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a forma mais simples de fazer funcionar é efetuando uma conversão, colocando `(double)`,`(float)` ou `(real)` antes da atribuição do valor.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$examesEquipamentos = [];
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
  $examesEquipamentosId = trim($linha['ID']) . '-' . trim($linha['ID_TR']);
  if (!array_key_exists($examesEquipamentosId, $examesEquipamentos)) {
    $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = [
      'ID' => trim($linha['ID']),
      'NOME_PARAMETRO' => trim($linha['NOME_PARAMETRO']),
      'ID_TR' => trim($linha['ID_TR']),
      'TR_NOME' => trim(mb_strtoupper($linha['TR_NOME'])),
      'UNIDADE_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']),
      'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']),
      'LIMITE_INFERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_INFERIOR']),
      'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => (double)$linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR'], //<-- Conversão aqui.
    ];
  }
}
```

> Documentação aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: a questão aqui é: esse LIMITE_SUPERIOR está pegando valores a partir de uma csv e neste csv tem linhas do campos LIMITE_SUPERIOR QUE VEM PREENCHIDOS pq há valores dentro do arquivos csv e tem linhas deste campo que estão vazios. gostaria simplesmente de retornar 0 quando ele encontra um campo vazio e quando encontra um campo já preenchido que ele faz nada e deixa esse campo preenchido.

Comment: Testou o código?

Comment: vc tinha razão deu certo. ele colocou zero só nas linhas do campo vazios e os campos preenchidos deixou como estava. Valeu @Laércio Lopes

Comment: e como eu posso fazer para somente listar as linhas do campo não vazio ? exemplo 'ID' => trim($linha['ID']), se o id vir vazio que pule e não liste aquela linha que possui o id vazio. estou gerando um script sql pelo arquivo csv. Não sei se fiquei pelo menos claro com a minha pergunta amigo.

Comment: Ficou claro sim, teste `trim($linha['ID'])` se está null ou vazio. Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2639/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-null-empty-0-e-false

Comment: Também: http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/verificar-variavel-vazia-em-php

Comment: Teste antes de atribuir o array.

Comment: @ Laércio Lopes infelizmente não consegui implementar isso seguindo o exemplo do meu código. :( não sei mais o que fazer ja perdi 2horas nisso

Answer (score 3):

Usando uma versão encurtada do [operador ternário](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) fica legível, simples e conciso:

```
<?php
echo trim("") ?: 0;     // 0
echo trim("2.5") ?: 0;  // "2.5"
```

Explicando, a partir do PHP 5.3 é possível omitir a parte do meio do operador ternário:

```
<?php
echo $x ? $x : 0;
// é o mesmo que
echo $x ?: 0;
```

Ou seja, se o valor de `$x` for [*Truthy*](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) imprime `$x`, senão o valor depois do `?:`, que neste caso é `0`.

---

Seu exemplo ficaria:

```
<?php

$examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = [
    // ...
    'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']) ?: 0,
    // ...
];
```

Comment: a sua resposta está boa, porém ele vai substituir até as linhas do campo que já tem valores preenchidos. eu só quero que ele preencha os campos que estão vazios. ai que está o problema com a sua resposta

Comment: Você testou? Se `trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR'])` for uma string vazia ele preenche, senão não preenche.

Comment: Olhe [aqui](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-358372-6333) este mesmo código rodando.

Comment: Valeu amigo a sua resposta também está BOA!!! testei aqui e deu certo. eu tinha colocado coisa errada antes. Mas a sua resposta e do outro colega está certa.Valeu por ter me ajudado!!!

Comment: e como eu posso fazer para somente listar as linhas do campo não vazio ? exemplo 'ID' => trim($linha['ID']), se o id vir vazio que pule e não liste. estou gerando um script sql pelo arquivo csv. Não sei se fiquei pelo menos claro com a minha pergunta amigo.

Comment: Você pode usar a função [`array_filter()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) para remover qualquer valor indesejado, veja [este exemplo](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-358372-6333-2). Lembre que `'0'` é false para o PHP.

Comment: Peço desculpa mas eu não consegui encaixar isso dentro do meu código :( apesar que que seu exemplo estava bastante claro para mim...se puder ajudar eu agradeceria muito @fernandosavio

Comment: É só adicionar depois de montar o seu array ou enquanto monta mesmo. [Olha aqui](https://gist.github.com/fernandosavio/d026bae33bba4ad97f9507842e683025).

Comment: estranho mas ele continua retornando a linha com o campo id que está vazio. mesmo do jeito que fiz deu na mesma.Tentei do seu jeito deu na mesma. Não consegui entender o pq

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar um if ternário com o empty para checar se veio nulo, fica assim.

```
'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => empty($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']) ? 0 : trim(empty($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR'])
```

Comment: eu vou testar para ver @Renan Chaves

Comment: a sua resposta foi boa, porém a onde ele encontro um valor ele substituiu por zero. eu só queria que ele coloque zero a onde vem vazio e a onde ja tem um valor quele faz nada.

Comment: A sim me desculpa fiz um ctrl+C e ctrl+V tinha que ter removido o empty()  da segunda parte o empty retorna um booleano por isso onde tinha valor ele estava colocando 0 pois possuia conteúdo e o retorno ela false ou 0 no caso.
'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => empty($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']) ? 0 : trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR'])

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso abaixo:

```
$examesEquipamentos = [];

$limite_superior = "";
foreach ($csv as $linha) {
if(trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']) == null){
        $limite_superior = 0;
}else{
        $limite_superior = trim($linha['LIMITE_SUPERIOR']);
}
$examesEquipamentosId = trim($linha['ID']) . '-' . trim($linha['ID_TR']);
if (!array_key_exists($examesEquipamentosId, $examesEquipamentos)) {
    $examesEquipamentos[$examesEquipamentosId] = [
        'ID' => trim($linha['ID']),
        'NOME_PARAMETRO' => trim($linha['NOME_PARAMETRO']),
        'ID_TR' => trim($linha['ID_TR']),
        'TR_NOME' => trim(mb_strtoupper($linha['TR_NOME'])),
        'UNIDADE_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['UNIDADE_RESULTADO']),
        'CATEGORIA_RESULTADO' => trim($linha['CATEGORIA_RESULTADO']),
        'LIMITE_INFERIOR' => trim($linha['LIMITE_INFERIOR']),
        'LIMITE_SUPERIOR' => trim($limite_superior),
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: Eu vou testar @Douglas

Comment: eu não consegui entender bem o que seu código faz. $limite_superior vc o colocou como uma variavel enquanto em nenhum momento ele foi declarado.

Comment: Você pode declarar fora do foreach. Eu acabei esquecendo de declarar.